git blobless clone hangs for a long time
When I run this command:
GIT_CONFIG_NOSYSTEM=1 GIT_CONFIG_NOGLOBAL=1 /bin/git clone --filter=blob:none https://github.com/movableink/webkit.git /tmp/webkit

It hangs for a few minutes after:
Resolving deltas: 100% (1962290/1962290), done.

Why?  Any way to prevent this?
